# Is it advisable to apply to more than one PhD program?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application

Is it good to apply for more than one PhD program and accept ( the best case, obviously ) the most interesting/best paid/best outlooks one?

Comment: Sorry, we don't offer university recommendations here, so I've edited out that part of the question. I've also edited out your "background" section since it seems unnecessary for answering the question.

Comment: I would say that applying to just one program would be downright crazy.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Last time I checked, I was not crazy.

Comment: @Sverre Don't be so sure.

Comment: @Sverre Clearly you haven't read Catch-22. (this comment is intended to be humorous)

Comment: @JeffE I said last time _I_ checked ``:)``

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is common to send multiple PhD applications to multiple schools. I am doing this now, I would RECOMMEND it actually because getting into PhD programs is difficult.

Comment: Open positions usually get 200-800 applications for a single opening. So yes, it is difficult to get in.